# Как переименовать имя узла TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

```
void SaveHeadToE(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
            TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;

            if (item != null)
            {

                //ничего не происходит
                item.Name = textBlockHead.Text;
                //имя исчезает. вместо имени пустое место
                item.Header = textBlockHead.Text;
```

Обновление дерева происходит так:

```
tw_tree.ItemsSource = null;
tw_tree.ItemsSource = node.collection_node;
```

Но при этом Дерево полностью сворачивается

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о том, чтобы изменить строку с которой данный узел отображается в дереве, можно попробовать так

```
item.Text = textBlockHead.Text;
```